# Resources for working with video feeds in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, video, video-capture, motion-detection

I'm starting to get into a side project that I hope to pull in frames from several small IP cameras, perhaps do a bit of motion detection and redisplay them in a form with alerts.

Does anyone have some good resources or similar projects that I could use to get acquainted with the ins and outs?  I'm using C# 3.5 with SP1 in VS2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx) you can find an article on how to do motion detection between images. It's based on the [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) library, which, quoting their site:

> AForge.NET is a C# framework designed for developers and researchers in the fields of Computer Vision and Artificial Intelligence - image processing, neural networks, genetic algorithms, machine learning, etc.